# Poker program to get # of hands better than hero's hand

Tags: java, poker

So i have an app which can calculate the number of uniqe and valid hands that have a higher % of chance to win vs. a hero hand given a board from 0-5 cards. The code is below..

```
public static HashSet<Hand> getCombos(Hand h, int n) {
    HashSet<Card> cards = new HashSet<Card>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 52; i++)
        cards.add(new Card(i));
    HashSet<Hand> combos = new HashSet<Hand>();
    HashSet<Card> inner = dupe(cards);
    inner.removeAll(h.cards);
    recur(h, combos, inner, n);
    return combos;
}

public static Hand dupe(Hand h) {
    Hand h1 = new Hand();
    h1.cards.addAll(h.cards);
    return h1;
}
public static HashSet<Card> dupe(HashSet<Card> cards) {
    return new HashSet<Card>(cards);
}

public static void recur(Hand curr, HashSet<Hand> combos, HashSet<Card> cards, int n) {
    if (curr.cards.size() == n && curr.isValid()) {
        combos.add(dupe(curr));
    } else {
        HashSet<Card> inner = dupe(cards);
        for (Card c : cards) {
            inner.remove(c);
            curr.add(c);
            recur(curr, combos, inner, n);
            curr.remove(c);
        }
    }
}

public static int numOfBetter(Hand hand, Hand board) {

    HashSet<Hand> allBoards = getCombos(board, 5);
    board.cards.clear();
    HashSet<Hand> allHands = getCombos(board, 2);
    for (Iterator<Hand> iterator = allHands.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Hand h = iterator.next();
        if ((h.contains(hand.cards.get(0)) || h.contains(hand.cards.get(1))) && !hand.equals(h))
            iterator.remove();
    }
    HashMap<Hand, Integer> results = new HashMap<Hand, Integer>();
    for (Hand h : allHands)
        results.put(h, 0);
    for (Hand b : allBoards)
        for (Hand h1 : allHands)
            for (Hand h2 : allHands) {
                Hand curr1 = b.combine(h1);
                Hand curr2 = b.combine(h2);
                if (h1.validMatchup(h2) && curr1.isValid() && curr2.isValid() && curr1.isBetterThan(curr2))
                    results.put(h1, results.get(h1) + 1);
            }
    HashSet<Integer> betterSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (Hand h : results.keySet()) {
        if (results.get(h) > results.get(hand))
            betterSet.add(h.handCode());
    }

    return betterSet.size();


}
```

What it basically does is this...

1) Create all 2 card hands that don't include any of hero's cards (basically all hands that an opponent could have)

2) Create all possible complete (5 card) boards that can be made from the supplied incomplete (or complete) board.

3) Test every hand against every other hand, for every board, checking to ensure each matchup is valid (a "matchup" is valid when both hands being matched against eachother, as well as the board don't contain any of the same cards.

4) store # of total wins in a  hashmap

5) get all hands that have more wins than hero's hand

6) reduce the result set by similar cards (ie. if 8 of spades/9 of hearts and 8 of diamonds/9 of hearts are both in the "betterThan" set, only one will be counted)

7) return the number of unique hands that have a higher percentage of winning compared to hero's hand

Now, this program does seem to work correctly. The problem is it take a very long time to run. When you have 4 out of 5 cards it takes about 5-10 minutes. But when you only have 3, it takes like over 3 hours. I can't even imagine how long it would take for a less complete board.

The logic behind this program is that it will essentially test each valid hand against every other valid hand for every possible valid board and return the number of unique hands that win more often than the hero's hand. My isBetterThan() method seems pretty fast for those wondering.

Is there a better (faster) way to do this?

Edit:

Here's the Hand class:

```
public class Hand {
ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

public boolean isValid() {
    ArrayList<Card> allCards = new ArrayList<Card>(this.cards);
    HashSet<Card> cardSet = new HashSet<Card>(allCards);
    if (allCards.size() == cardSet.size())
        return true;
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Hand h = (Hand) o;
    for (Card c : h.cards)
    if (!this.contains(c))
        return false;
    return true;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int code = 0;
    for (Card c : this.cards)
        code += c.val + Character.getNumericValue(c.suit);
    return code;
}
public void add(Card c) {
    if (!this.contains(c))
        this.cards.add(c);
}
public void remove(Card c) {
    if (this.contains(c))
        this.cards.remove(c);
}
public boolean containsVal(int i) {
    for (Card c : this.cards)
        if (c.val == i)
            return true;
    return false;
}
public int handCode() {
    int code = 0;
    if (this.cards.get(0).val == this.cards.get(1).val)
        return this.cards.get(0).val;
    else if (this.cards.get(0).val > this.cards.get(1).val)
        code = this.cards.get(0).val * 100 + this.cards.get(1).val;
    else
        code = this.cards.get(1).val * 100 + this.cards.get(0).val;
    if (this.cards.get(0).suit == this.cards.get(1).suit)
        code*=100;
    return code;
}
public Hand combine(Hand h) {
    Hand ha = new Hand();
    ha.cards.addAll(h.cards);
    ha.cards.addAll(this.cards);
    return ha;
}
public boolean contains(Card c) {
    for (Card ca : this.cards)
        if (ca.val == c.val && c.suit == ca.suit)
            return true;
    return false;
}
public int getHandStr() {
    int str = 0;
    if (this.isPair(2))
        str = 1;
    if (this.isTwoPair())
        str = 2;
    if (this.isPair(3))
        str = 3;
    if (this.isStraight())
        str = 4;
    if (this.isFlush())
        str = 5;
    if (this.isFullHouse())
        str = 6;
    if (this.isPair(4))
        str = 7;
    if (this.isFlush() && this.isStraight())
        str = 8;
    if (this.isFlush() && this.isStraight() && this.containsVal(14) && this.containsVal(13))
        str = 9;
    return str;
}
public int getTopXSum(int x) {
    int sum = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Card c : this.cards)
        vals.add(c.val);
    Collections.sort(vals);
    Collections.reverse(vals);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i : vals) {
        sum+=i;
        count++;
        if (count == x)
            return sum;
    }
    return 0;

}
public boolean isBetterThan(Hand h) {
    if (h.getHandStr() == this.getHandStr()) {
        if (this.isFullHouse()) {
            if (this.fullHouseVal()[0] > h.fullHouseVal()[0])
                return true;
            else if (this.fullHouseVal()[0] == h.fullHouseVal()[0])
                if (this.fullHouseVal()[1] > h.fullHouseVal()[1])
                    return true;
            return false;
        }
        if (this.isStraight()) {
            if (this.getStraightVal() > h.getStraightVal())
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        if (this.getTopXSum(4) > h.getTopXSum(4))
            return true;
        else if (this.getTopXSum(5) > h.getTopXSum(5))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } else if (this.getHandStr() > h.getHandStr())
        return true;
    return false;
}
public boolean isFlush() {
    char[] suits = {'s', 'h', 'd', 'c'};
    int count;
    for (int i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
        count = 0;
        for (Card c : this.cards) {
            if (c.suit == suits[i])
                count++;
            if (count == 5)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public int getStraightVal() {
    for (Card c : this.cards) {
        if (this.containsVal(c.val+1) && this.containsVal(c.val+2) && this.containsVal(c.val+3) && this.containsVal(c.val+4))
            return c.val+4;
        if (this.containsVal(14) && this.containsVal(2) && this.containsVal(3) && this.containsVal(4) && this.containsVal(5))
            return 5;
    }
    return 0;
}
public boolean isStraight() {
    for (Card c : this.cards) {
        if (this.containsVal(c.val+1) && this.containsVal(c.val+2) && this.containsVal(c.val+3) && this.containsVal(c.val+4))
            return true;
        if (this.containsVal(14) && this.containsVal(2) && this.containsVal(3) && this.containsVal(4) && this.containsVal(5))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean isTwoPair() {
    int count;
    int pairs = 0;
    int prevPair = 0;
    for (Card c : this.cards) {
        count = 0;
        for (Card ca : this.cards)
            if (ca.val == c.val && c.val != prevPair)
                count++;
        if (count == 2) {
            pairs++;
            prevPair = c.val;
        }
    }
    if (pairs == 2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
public int[] fullHouseVal() {
    int[] vals = new int[2];
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.cards.size(); i++) {
        c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < this.cards.size(); j++) {
            if (this.cards.get(i).val == this.cards.get(j).val)
                c++;
            if (c == 3)
                vals[0] = this.cards.get(i).val;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < this.cards.size(); i++) {
        c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < this.cards.size(); j++) {
            if ((this.cards.get(i).val == this.cards.get(j).val) && this.cards.get(i).val != vals[0])
                c++;
            if (c == 2)
                vals[1] = this.cards.get(i).val;
        }
    }
    return vals;
}
public boolean isFullHouse() {
    int count;
    int prevPair = 0;
    for (Card c : this.cards) {
        count = 0;
        for (Card ca : this.cards)
            if (ca.val == c.val)
                count++;
        if (count == 3)
            prevPair = c.val;
    }
    for (Card c : this.cards) {
        count = 0;
        for (Card ca : this.cards)
            if (ca.val == c.val && c.val != prevPair) {
                count++;
                if (count == 2 && prevPair != 0)
                    return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean isPair(int i) {
    int count;
    for (Card c : this.cards) {
        count = 0;
        for (Card ca : this.cards)
            if (ca.val == c.val)
                count++;
        if (count == i)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public boolean validMatchup(Hand h) {
    return h.combine(this).isValid();
}
```

}

Comment: Shown code is incomplete and as such it is next to impossible to see where the bottle neck is. Do you have Hand class somewhere ?

Comment: @MaxZoom I have a Hand and Card class. Like i mentioned though, the method that checks if a hand is better, seems to run fairly fast (calculates instantly, but i know that run time adds up). I'm fairly sure it's my getCombos() method that is slow but i'm not sure if there's a more efficient way

Comment: So what you are doing is basically take 7 cards out of 50 (5 to the board + 2 to the player) and see how many the player wins? That is the 99 884 400 combinations that need to be run through "calculates instantly") So even if the code takes 1µs, it will take about 2h to complete. :)

Comment: @ViktorMellgren is there a better way?

Comment: I think you can find that you can reduce the problem a bit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability_(Texas_hold_'em), and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability_(Texas_hold_'em)#cite_note-pruning-1 in particular.

Comment: @ViktorMellgren does that apply to partially completed boards though? For example with 2 clubs on the board, 8c7h holds more equity than 8h7c which holds more equity than 8h7d

Comment: Take a look at my onejoker library. There's a Java binding for it, but I'm not a Java guy, so I haven't tested it extensively. The library itself is in C, and can do *millions* of hand evaluations per second.

Comment: Why are you calculating boards with less than 3 cards? That will never happen in a game of Texas Hold'em.

Comment: @HerbWolfe I'm not, but i want to calculate for boards with 0,3,4, and 5 cards

Comment: Here is the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands) of poker hands that has been already calculated in advance. It can be used to greatly simplify number of higher hands in your program. You could also use it to modify your hand  evaluation in a method `getHandStr(..)`. What are `14` and `13` magic numbers in last condition there?

Comment: @MaxZoom Royal Flush, straight and flush that includes ace (14) and king (13)